# Half Life 1 Local Game Server fail

Tags: technical-issues, half-life

I bought Half Life 1 on Steam and wanted to play it but if I click New Game and choose training there the Game stucks on starting Local Game Server. I reinstalled it but it wasn't working.

Additional info:
Windows 7 x68, Enough RAM and CPU, no Windows Firewall, Avast! Antivirus

Comment: Can you actually somehow play the game? Like Single Player, Local Multiplayer or Online Multiplayer? Because in the requirements Windows XP is suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy **Steam.dll** from `Steam` folder to `Steam\SteamApps\<user>\half-life`.
Same for "Blue Shift" (`Steam\SteamApps\<user>\half-life blue shift`) and "Opposing Force" (`Steam\SteamApps\<user>\opposing force`).

If game crashes at start, see answer from Hidduh (Add `hl.exe` to *Start > Control Panel > System > Advanced > Performance > Data Execution Prevention*).

Answer (score 1):

This is the fix for Half-Life 1 Single Player not working(Freezing while Starting Local Game Server)

If you are opt into the "Steam Beta Update" It will sometimes break a lot of your games because it is updating with unofficially released updates. To disable it,

-Open up Steam

-Click on the Steam tab in the top left corner of the page

-Select Settings

-Under the Account tab there should be an option for beta participation

-Set Beta Participation to "NONE - opt out of all beta programs"

-When it asks you to Restart steam, click Restart

The Steam client should then restart and update itself to the correct version and you should be able to play without any problems

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: 
https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8079-KZXN-6067